# React state resets when used with a composite object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React. Here is the scenario:

- I have a class called Book. A book has a title and content, both strings.
- I'm trying to separate the concerns within the book page into a BookComponent (view) and Book hook (state) and a Book class (dealing with the backend API), similar to what's described here: https://martinfowler.com/articles/modularizing-react-apps.html

Here is a sample code:

```js
export const useBook = () => {
  const [book, setBook] = React.useState<Book>(new Book('', ''))
 
  function load(id: string) {
    Book.fetch(id).then((book) => { setBook(book) })
  }
  
  function title() : string {
     return book.title
  }

  function content() : string {
     return book.content 
  }

  function setTitle(title: string) {
    setBook({ ...book, title })
  }

  function setContent(content: string) {
    setBook({ ...book, content })
  }

  return {
    title,
    setTitle,
    content,
    setContent
  }
}
```

In the BookComponent (view) I have this:

```html
<div>{book.title()}</div>
<input type="text" value={book.content()} onChange={(e) => book.setContent(e.target.value) }} />
```

(Omitted `useEffect` code to load the book)

The page shows the title and the content correctly. However, as soon as I type anything in the textbox, the title goes back to `""` which is the initial value of the state.

I thought using `setBook({...book, content})` within the hook is going to copy the existing book state and only modify `content`, but it seems the code enters `setContent` with a brand new `book` when I inspect `...book`

Changing the state to the following fixes the problem:

```js
const [book, setBook] = React.useState<Book | null>(null)
// ...
function title() : string {
 if (!book) return { '' }
 
 return book.title
}
// same for content
```

But I don't understand why the state would start from a `null` value (default) every time and the lifecycle of it.

Comment: If you want `book` to be an instance of `Book` spreading isn't going to help you anyway, that creates a vanilla object that just has the same properties, not an actual instance (`({ ...book }) instanceof Book` is false).

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe I thought that's the case (perhaps thinking some typescript magic would happen when the spread is on a typed instance). What would be the correct way of creating a `Book` object? a full `new` statement manually populating all properties?

Comment: TypeScript **does not exist** at runtime, all of the type metadata is erased in compilation. Classes do still exist, but there's no extra code to make spreading somehow do something different. And yes, either `new` one up or maybe add methods for that behaviour (e.g. `book.with({ author: "New Author" })`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your new state like this (with a callback fn) inside your `setContent` (and similarly in `setTitle`) with an access to previous state and it should work exactly as you expected. Copy prevState with spread operateor into a new state and override content:

```
setBook(prevState => ({ ...prevState, content }))
```